# Matlab - plotting function with a for loop over a matrix

Tags: matlab, plot

I have an assignment which sounds like:
"“Grades per assignment”: A plot with the assignments on the x-axis and the grades on the y-axis. The x-axis must show all assignments from 1 to M, and the y-axis must show all grade −3 to 12. The plot must contain:

1. Each of the given grades marked by a dot. You must add a small random number (between -0.1 and 0.1) to the x- and y-coordinates of each dot, to be able tell apart the different dots which otherwise would be on top of each other when more than one student has received the same grade in the same assignment.
2. The average grade of each of the assignments plotted as a line"

For now i have created this function:

```
            function gradesPlot(grades)

            figure(2);
            n_assignments=size(grades,2);
            
            hold on;                   % Retain current plot when adding new plots.
            for i = 1:n_assignments    % Loop through every assignment.
                % Scatter plot of assignment vs grades for that assignment.
                % One assignment on every iteration.
                n_assignments2=([1:size(grades,2)]);
                
                scatter(n_assignments2,grades(:,i)'jitter', 'on', 'jitterAmount', 0.1)
                hold off; % Set the hold state to off.
            end
          
            %Titles to the plot
            title('Grades per assignment');
            xlabel('Assignment');
            ylabel('Given grades');
            break;
            end
```

when i run the code it says that the vectors must be same length.
And it looks like it doesn't loop over the matrix more than ones.

The test grades i am using as input is looking like this:
grades=[[-3,4,10];[7,4,12];[7,10,12];[0,4,4];[2,2,2];[2,2,2]]

I hope some of you guys can help me get this function to work - maybe in an easier way?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Interesting, because this code should error for other reasons, for example the clear typo "`grades(:,i)'jitter'`". This is not literally the code you tested, please do not post untested code!

Comment: i forgot to put the comma, if that is the fault. 

But i get this error: 
Error using scatter (line 88)
X and Y must be vectors of the same length, matrices of the same size, or a combination of a
vector and a matrix where the length of the vector matches either the number of rows or
columns of the matrix.

Error in gradesPlot (line 56)
                    scatter(n_assignments2,grades(:,i),'jitter', 'on', 'jitterAmount', 0.1);

Comment: `n_assignments2=([1:size(grades,1)]);`

Comment: You should also not turn off `hold`.

Comment: Thanks Chris, looks like this gives me an output, but unfortunately not the right one.. now it plots like there's 6 assignments in my test plot, but there are only 3. 
the vertical line in the matrix is number of assignments while the horizontal is the grades given - hope this makes sense.  

And can you tell why i should turn off hold?

Answer (score 1):

You should not turn off `hold` since it is tells MatLab to plot everything in the current active plot, roughly speaking. You can find a possible solution to your problem down below: I added some explanations in comments.

```
function gradesPlot(grades)

figure(2);
% Extract the relevant information: number of assignements, number of grades
[n_assignments,n_grades] = size(grades);

hold on;                   % Retain current plot when adding new plots.
for i = 1:n_assignments    % Loop through every assignment.
    % Scatter plot of assignment vs grades for that assignment.
    % One assignment on every iteration
    
    % For Scatter, you have to provide 2 vectors of the same size: in this
    % way, we are putting al the dots corresponding to the grades of the
    % i-th assignement in correspondence of the i-th coordinate on the x
    % axis. We are also temporary saving in h the handle to the attributes
    % of the dots, in order to retrieve the color.
    h = scatter(i*ones(n_grades,1),grades(i,:),'jitter', 'on', 'jitterAmount', 0.1);
    
    % This plots the horizontal line corresponding to the average of the
    % grades related to the i-th assignement
    l = line([i-0.5 i+0.5],[1,1]*mean(grades(i,2:end)));
    % For using the same color as the dots.
    l.Color = h.CData;
end

%Titles to the plot
title('Grades per assignment');
xlabel('Assignment');
ylabel('Given grades');
axis([0 n_assignments+1 -4 13])
end
```

Remember that the `break` command must be used inside a loop, not for exiting a function. Use `return` if you desire.